# Loop over csv file with multiple fields

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

Could anyone help out with this one please .Let s say I have a csv text file with 2 fields as per below

```
Name    Age 
Adam    24
Claire  36
Ian     65
Jamal   42
```

[Image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDBNJ.png)

How do I create script that loops over the names and another that applies the age to the corresponding name by using the above data . Ideally i would like to get an output in the form of" Adam is 24  "and so on

Sorry just getting into python

Thanks

Comment: You should at least tell us what you've attempted, since a question is not a request of code/scripts: if someone just writes the code for you, you won't learn nothing.

Comment: I have tried and failed , but good point . Will keep in mind.  This is my first post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First calling your `csv` file

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('excel.xlsx')
```

This is how my `excel sheet` looks like

```
Name    Age 
Adam    24
Claire  36
Ian     65
Jamal   42
```

Then you can use this

```
for i in range(len(df)):
  print(df['Name'][i], 'is', df['Age'][i])
```

Output:

```
Adam is 24
Claire  is 36
Ian is 65
Jamal is 42
```

Comment: Thanks ,I ll give it a go . Much appreciated